# Response xml from server using curl

Tags: php, xml, web-services, api, curl

I want to make an API call with code

```
<?php    
$url = "url";
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $data;
if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and hope that the response will be like this

```
<GoodreadsResponse>
<GoodreadsResponse>
  <Request>
    <!-- ... request metadata omitted ... -->
  </Request>
  <search>
    <query>
      <![CDATA[ Ender's Game ]]>
    </query>
    <results-start>1</results-start>
    <results-end>10</results-end>
    <total-results>100</total-results>
    <source>Goodreads</source>
    <query-time-seconds>0.10</query-time-seconds>        
  </search>
  ....
</GoodreadsResponse>
```

but when I execute that code, it returns in browser like this

```
true 1 20 386 Goodreads 0.39 2422333 207 690938 33000 1985 4.28 375802 589 Orson Scott Card https://d.gr-assets.com/book ......
```

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

when use in Browser, than show Sourcecode (rightclick -> show sourcecode) for unrendered view.

```
<?php
$request = "";
$curl = curl_init("https://www.goodreads.com/search.xml?key=9ZzEFHzs9LwIdA3qt0fMw&q=Ender%27s+Game");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($response); echo "</pre>";
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

This URL when I paste in the browser returns correct XML.

https://www.goodreads.com/search.xml?key=9ZzEFHzs9LwIdA3qt0fMw&q=Ender%27s+Game

Your browser may be displaying the XML as text. View the source of the page and see if you can view the full XML response.

Also you just pasted the API key here for everyone to see. You might want to change it now to avoid problems with anyone else using/abusing it.

Comment: Oh yes, browser handle response as html, not xml, how can I fix this, I have set content-type : text/xml but it doesnot work